# pandas filtering ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter a dataframe with itseld in a for loop:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    res1 = df[(df.index != idx) & (df.start >= row.start) & (df.end <= row.end)]
    res = pd.concat([res, res1])
```

But the first line of the loop (the filtering) is returning me this:

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2920,) (2921,)

I have no idea why

Dataframe is shaped:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['start','end','seq','record','len','ir_1','ir_2'])
```

Data is added like this:

```
with l_lock:
    new_element = [ir_start, ir_end,ir_seq, record.id, ir_len, seq_q, seq_q_prime]
    df.loc[len(df)] = new_element
```

with different threads, maybe it has something to do with it.

What I cannot do is to filter as stated in the first part of the post

If I run

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

before the loop, the error I get is:

```
IRMatcher.py:235: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
  res1 = df[(df.index != idx) & (df.start >= row.start) & (df.end <= row.end)]
99% 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "IRMatcher.py", line 235, in <module>
    res1 = df[(df.index != idx) & (df.start >= row.start) & (df.end <= row.end)]
  File "/home/trigo/runs/irmatcher/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2133, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "/home/trigo/runs/irmatcher/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2173, in _getitem_array
    key = check_bool_indexer(self.index, key)
  File "/home/trigo/runs/irmatcher/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 2023, in check_bool_indexer
    raise IndexingError('Unalignable boolean Series provided as '
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match
```

Comment: what excactly you want to do?? can you share some sample data,

Comment: @EspoirMurhabazi I cannot run this:     res1 = df[(df.index != idx) & (df.start >= row.start) & (df.end <= row.end)]

Answer (score 0):

IIUC: Using list storage your temp df

```
l=[]
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    res1 = df[(df.index != idx) & (df.start >= row.start) & (df.end <= row.end)]
    l.append(res1)

pd.concat(l)
```